# What is 'the Rails way' to have forms not directly mapped to an object model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Let's say I have three tables to accommodate a many-to-many relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_hobbies
    has_many :hobbies, :through => :user_hobbies
end
class UserHobbies < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :hobby
end
class Hobby < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_hobbies
    has_many :users, :through => :user_hobbies
end
```

And I wanted to have a form in which a user can input as many hobbies as they want, where each would be stored into the correct tables (in my situation, the 'Hobby' table is preset, the user may select from enumerated values, not add them)

How would I go about producing a form to achieve this? I would use JavaScript for Auto-Completion and dynamic fields (i.e. each time you enter a field, another appears).

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce this form there are two options which are available to you..

a. The first option is to use the virtual attribute which would accept the comma separated values of the hobbies of the user and then when you save the user the virtual attribute would then set the hobbies corresponding to the respective user..See this railcast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

b. The second option is to use the accepts_nested_attributes_for which would automatically include the attributes for the nested relationships in the parent model...Consult the API for more information on accepts_nested_attributes_for

Also I can see a bug in the above definitions as there should be has_many :users :through :user_hobbies relationship in the Hobbies table becoz we might want to know the user having the..

As far as the auto-completion is concerned, there is a gem called as auto-complete-rails and its documentation is pretty simple and standard to use and understand..

Comment: Just wrote that as an example for this question, and assumed that the relationship would not need to be tracked in that 'direction'. I just added the transitive relationship for completeness.

Comment: Currently looking into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Seems to be what I want, just need to figure out how to put it all together.

Comment: Personally I would recommend this to you but in my initial days of learning Rails I would use virtual attributes